How to properly write into a database with multithreading?
I'm trying to write in a single database from multiple threads using Rust, I need to write lots of lines into the db so with a single thread the process is really slow (30 min or more) as this is for a test I decided to add more threads, the problem is that it doesn't seem to increase the speed of the process by a lot.
Any tips on how to properly do this on Rust? This is the code I have right now, I was thinking on manage the retry because sometimes the threads panic because they find the db locked, this is beyond this specific question but if you want to help too it will be appreciated anyway:
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use std::{sync::{atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering}, Arc}, thread, time};
    use common::store::StoreConnection;
    use reports::bat_osc::BatOscData;

    const TEST_DB: &str = "/tmp/test_database.db";

    fn write_entries(count: &AtomicU32) {
        while count.load(Ordering::Relaxed) < 7000000 {
  
            if count.load(Ordering::Relaxed) % 1000 == 0 {
                println!("{}", count.load(Ordering::Relaxed));
            }

            let store = StoreConnection::new(TEST_DB, reports::bat_osc::BAT_OSC_TABLE)
            .unwrap()
            .writer(2592000 * 2)
            .unwrap();
        
            let data = BatOscData {
                ..Default::default()
            };

            let _ = store.insert(data);
            count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        }
    }
    

    #[test]
    fn write_a_lot() {
        let count = Arc::new(AtomicU32::new(0));
        let mut handles = vec![];

        // Create several threads
        for _ in 0..1000 {
            let count_clone = Arc::clone(&count);
            let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                write_entries(&count_clone);
            });
            handles.push(handle);
        }

        // Join all the threads
        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().expect("Thread panicked");
        }

    }
}

Trying to write into a db with multiple threads to increase speed of the process. Speed doesn't increase at all.

It seems that you create a new connection to the DB 7000000 times. You should keep only one connection open and reuse it. And instead of inserting each single data, you should probably prepare a medium size batch and send it in a transaction (not so often). Thousands of threads won't help, because your system won't schedule them very often, and they will just overload the DB server (or file-system, if it is something like sqlite) with simultaneous requests.

What kind of DB are you using?

I'm using sqlite3, I will try to use batches and reuse the connection and see if that fixes the problem, thanks

Using batches improved a lot the performance but multi-threading didn't, if someone need to implement the same I ended up following this guide: https://avi.im/blag/2021/fast-sqlite-inserts/
